# How to convince an annoyed user

Tags: conflict-resolution, user-engagement

A user is discouraged/disgruntled as some of his answers are deleted by a moderator. He thinks he has not got proper justification and plans to leave or stop contributing to the community.

How to convince that user and make him understand that community likes him, is not prejudiced, and will surely take action if needed?

He is knowledgeable and helps the community with his contributions, so we would like to 'keep' him.

Comment: I have edited your question, but am still unsure what you mean with *there will surely action be taken if needed*?

Comment: Why was the content deleted? Was it inappropriate in some way? Did you communicate this to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, it comes down to communication and determining what is an ok level of compromise.  If posts were being moderated away, then clearly the user has a mix of positive and negative contribution.

The user clearly shows promise and positive impact in the community, so the first step is to try to communicate with them about why the negative impacts are a problem and how to better avoid them.  This is unfortunately not something that can easily be summed up in a short answer and greatly depends on the individual in question and what issues their posts have.

If this doesn't work, it comes down to making a judgement call about the overall contributions the user makes, both good and bad, and compromising if you can.  If they post a lot of really great content and are of value to the community, then giving them some latitude may be worth it if you can do so without it feeling unfair or setting a bad example for others (not really sure what the problem was so can't really tell if it's possible in this case.)

This is a big judgement call on the moderation side, but if you lack the communication and persuasion skills to convince them to change, then it comes down to deciding if they are or are not an overall positive contribution to the community with all things considered.  If they are, you give them the needed latitude, if they are not, you shut them down and take the loss of the positive and the negative together.

Answer (score 8):

Background: You cannot force trust, but build it. People remember what they **feel**, what they **experience**.

Proposal:
Next time this user makes a post that is likely to be moderated,

- do not moderate, but engage first
- have a proper discussion with him, publicly (like a "comment" here on this platform, regarding an answer) or behind the scene (private message), or obviously a real talk
- point user to Term of Use so he/she understands rationale, and has ability to share perspective

Answer (score 7):

Why would his answers be deleted when he "helps the community with his contributions?" If you're deleting due to inaccuracy, then I question the "helps" statement. If you're deleting due to tone of voice, then a conversation with him about that might help him understand. Sounds like a dialog with him about why you delete his answers could be helpful. Can you engage him in other ways, as an admin, for example? By gaining responsibility for managing the community he may be better able to create content that supports the community's aims. Good luck!